# How to clear values from columns with the values "No" instead of NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a dataset that I'm going through and I have `No` values in some slots instead of `NaN` so I couldn't use the `dropna` method.  I believe that there is a specific way of looking for certain value in an entire dataset and performing operations on it but I don't know how that is done.

This is the csv I'm working with.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ryanleeallred/datasets/master/messy-data.csv

Comment: I don't see `NaN` values anywhere in your CSV file.  Did you leave something out?

Comment: What library are you using to parse csv?

Comment: @Tim I think he’s talking about the dataframe which would contain NaN for all the empty cellss

Comment: I don't know Pandas data frames.  Oh, the horror.

Comment: "I have a dataset that I'm going through and I have "No" values in some slots instead of NaN"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace `No` by `nan` and use `dropna`

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['Yes','No','No','Yes']})
df = df.replace('No',np.nan)
df.dropna()
```

Output:

```
    a
0   Yes
3   Yes
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I've accepted your answer and gave you an upvote.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?

Comment: @OnurOzbek Refer this: [How to create minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Next time when you ask a question on SO, follow these guidelines, you will get more upvotes. Upvoted  :-)